# Converting Java lambda to kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin, java-8

```
  public static Function<List<Object>, Function> required = objects -> (Function<FunctionKeeper, Object>) (wrapper) -> {
    if (LIVRUtils.isNoValue(wrapper.getValue())) {
        return "REQUIRED";
    }
    return "";
};
```

How do I convert this Java8 lambda approach to Kotlin lambda?

Comment: `wrapper` is a function, isn't it? If yes, it has no method `getValue()`. Is that code correct?

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I'm wondering the same...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky no I didn't

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val required = { objects: List<Any> ->
    { wrapper: FunctionKeeper ->
        if (LIVRUtils.isNoValue(wrapper.value)) {
            "REQUIRED"
        } else {
            ""
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `objects` is not used in your function.